# I can't login to the Gitlab Container registry in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, docker-registry, gitlab-ci-runner

I have this project structure

```
/sameer
|_ /certs
    |_ localhost-auth.crt
    |_ localhost-auth.csr
    |_ localhost-auth.key
|_ /projects
    |_ /sampleapp
        |_ ...[several python files]
        |_ Dockerfile
        |_ .gitlab-ci.yml
|_ docker-compose.yml
```

I have this `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: '2.2'

services:
  redis:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/redis:latest
#    ports:
#    - "6379:6379" #optional
    command:
    - --loglevel warning
    volumes:
    - redis:/var/lib/redis:Z

  postgresql:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/postgresql:9.5-3
    volumes:
    - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql:Z
    environment:
    - DB_USER=gitlab
    - DB_PASS=password
    - DB_NAME=gitlabhq_production
    - DB_EXTENSION=pg_trgm



  gitlab:
    cpu_count: 2 # as described here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/install/requirements.html#cpu
    mem_limit: 4000000000 # as described here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/install/requirements.html#memory
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/gitlab:10.1.1
#    build:
#      context: ./images/gitlab
#      dockerfile: Dockerfile
##      args:
##        buildno: 1
    volumes:
    - gitlab-data:/home/git/data:Z
    - gitlab-logs:/var/log/gitlab
    - ./certs:/certs
    depends_on:
    - redis
    - postgresql
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "2222:22"
    external_links:
    - "registry:registry"
    environment:
    - DEBUG=false

    - DB_ADAPTER=postgresql
    - DB_HOST=postgresql
    - DB_PORT=5432
    - DB_USER=gitlab
    - DB_PASS=password
    - DB_NAME=gitlabhq_production

    - REDIS_HOST=redis
    - REDIS_PORT=6379

    - GITLAB_HTTPS=false # <--- for some reason breaks when true
    - SSL_SELF_SIGNED=true # <---

    - GITLAB_HOST=192.168.99.101 # <---
    - GITLAB_PORT=80
    - GITLAB_SSH_PORT=2222
    - GITLAB_SHELL_SSH_PORT=2222
    - GITLAB_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT=
    - GITLAB_SECRETS_DB_KEY_BASE=secret
    - GITLAB_SECRETS_SECRET_KEY_BASE=secret
    - GITLAB_SECRETS_OTP_KEY_BASE=secret

    - GITLAB_REGISTRY_ENABLED=true
    - GITLAB_REGISTRY_HOST=localhost # <---

    - GITLAB_REGISTRY_PORT=5000
    - GITLAB_REGISTRY_API_URL=https://localhost:5000/ # Internal address to the registry, will be used by GitLab to directly communicate with API.

    - GITLAB_REGISTRY_CERT_PATH=/certs/localhost-auth.crt # <---
    - GITLAB_REGISTRY_KEY_PATH=/certs/localhost-auth.key # <---



  # Read :
  #https://hub.docker.com/r/sameersbn/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/
  #https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/
  #http://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html
  runner:
    restart: always
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
#    build:
#      context: ./images/gitlab-runner
#      dockerfile: Dockerfile
##      args:
##        buildno: 1
    volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # so the DinD can connect to the host's docker endpoint
    - ./certs:/etc/gitlab-runner/certs
    # Read
    # https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/README.html#using-environment-variables
    environment:
    - RUNNER_NAME=${GL_DEFAULT_RUNNER_NAME}

    - CI_SERVER_URL=http://192.168.99.101/ci/ # depending on the host
    - REGISTRATION_TOKEN=${TOKEN_FROM_GL_UI} # must be grabbed from "Admin Area->Overview->Runners"

    - RUNNER_EXECUTOR=docker
    - REGISTER_NON_INTERACTIVE=true # Run registration unattended

    - REGISTER_RUN_UNTAGGED=true
    - REGISTER_LOCKED=false
    - RUNNER_CACHE_DIR=cache
    - DOCKER_IMAGE=docker:latest
    - DOCKER_PRIVILEGED=true # If you want to use docker-in-docker mode, you always have to use privileged = true in your Docker containers
    - DOCKER_VOLUMES=/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # so the DinD can connect to the host's docker endpoint

    - CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE=/etc/gitlab-runner/certs/localhost-auth.cert
    - CI_SERVER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/gitlab-runner/certs/localhost-auth.cert
    - CI_SERVER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/gitlab-runner/certs/localhost-auth.key
#     - DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG=
#     - CONFIG_FILE=
#     - RUNNER_TAG_LIST=
#     - CI_SERVER_TOKEN=



#read here : https://m42.sh/gitlab-registry.html
  registry:
    restart: always
    image: registry:2.4.1
    ports:
    - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
    - registry-data:/var/lib/registry
    - ./certs:/certs
    external_links:
    - "gitlab:gitlab"
    environment:
    - REGISTRY_LOG_LEVEL=debug
    - REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true
    - REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY=/var/lib/registry

    - REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_REALM=https://localhost/jwt/auth # <---
    - REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_SERVICE=container_registry
    - REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_ISSUER=localhost
    - REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_ROOTCERTBUNDLE=/certs/localhost-auth.crt # <---

    - SSL_REGISTRY_KEY_PATH=/certs/localhost-auth.key # <---
    - SSL_REGISTRY_CERT_PATH=/certs/localhost-auth.crt # <---

    - REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/localhost-auth.crt # <---
    - REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/localhost-auth.key # <---
    - REGISTRY_HTTP_SECRET=secret



  portainer:
    restart: always
    image: portainer/portainer:1.15.1
    ports:
      - "9001:9000"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "/opt/portainer:/data"
    command: --no-auth



#  scope:
#    image: weaveworks/scope:latest #1.6.4
#    ports:
#      - "0.0.0.0:4040:4040"
##    network_mode: "host"
#    pid: "host"
#    privileged: true
#    labels:
#      - "works.weave.role=system"
#    volumes:
#      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw" # can be used on Linux only
#    command:
#      - "--probe.docker=true"



volumes:
    gitlab-data:
    gitlab-logs:
    postgresql:
    redis:
    registry-data:
```

and this `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

```
#image: docker:latest

variables:
  CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true" # makes the log extra verbose
  # When using dind, it's wise to use the overlayfs driver for improved performance.
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

#  -Gitlab registry vars-
#  CI_REGISTRY: registry:5000
#  CI_REGISTRY: 192.168.99.101:5000
  CI_REGISTRY: localhost:5000

##  -Azure registry vars-
#  AZURE_USER:
#  AZURE_PASS:
#  AZURE_REGISTRY_URL:

before_script:
#  -Gitlab registry login-
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
##  -Azure registry login-
#  - docker login -u $AZURE_USER -p $AZURE_PASS $AZURE_REGISTRY_URL

job1:
  image: docker:latest
  services:
  - docker:dind
  stage: build
  script:
  - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY/my-image .
  - docker push $CI_REGISTRY/my-image
#   - docker build -t $AZURE_REGISTRY_URL/my-image .
#   - docker push $AZURE_REGISTRY_URL/my-image
```

When I create the containers via `docker-compose up -d`, I get the registry to be enabled and I can see that is connected with the Gitlab server from the Gitlab UI [Projects -> sampleapp -> Registry]

[image: gitlab registry enabled]

Then I `commit` and `push` my code , and  Gitlab receives the job and forwards it to Gitlab-runner. Gitlab-runner is going to execute the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file where I am describing that I want the docker-executor(?) in the Gitlab-runner container to login to the registry , build my code into a container based on the provided Dockerfile, and then push it to the registry.

The problem is that it does not login to the registry!

From my countless tests, I understand that for some reason the runner tries to authenticate to the registry [through gitlab] but cannot.

Some of the errors I get are:

```
+ echo $ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
+ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx registry:5000
+ :
$ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry:5000/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry on 10.0.2.3:53: server misbehaving
```

or

```
+ echo $ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
+ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx localhost:5000
+ :
$ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get http://localhost:5000/v2/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: getsockopt: connection refused
```

or

```
+ echo $ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
+ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 192.168.99.101:5000
+ :
$ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get https://192.168.99.101:5000/v2/: x509: cannot validate certificate for 192.168.99.101 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

Also, from inside the runner container I can `ping` the registry fine.

As you can see in the `docker-compose.yml` file , I have provided as environmental variables the paths of the certificates to all relevant containers.

So , what am I doing wrong? Any pointer would be appreciated!

Comment: I have almost the same problem, but i have the Docker Registry running on an external server. The runners can Auth with the Regsitry but inside Gitlab EE, the registry page it is empty without images. Seems like a Auth problem. Have you found the problem in the meanwhile ?

Comment: Nope...I quit trying. I use an Azure private registry and everything runs smoothly.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: the `docker login` is executed in the global `before_script`. 
there is no `service: docker:dind` at that time.
You may want to execute the `docker login` in your job instead, where it will find a working DinD service.
... or put 
`
image: docker:stable
services:
  - docker:dind 
`
at the beginning of your CI file